# Need help selecting muiltiple div id's in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select multiple ID's using jquery. But the following code I wrote is not working.

```
var cat = $('.option_category').each(function() {
  var cat_id = cat.attr('id');
  console.log(cat_id');
});
});
```

Comment: `.option_category` are classes, not ID's.   Please post your html too.

Comment: I also think you want to refer to $(this) inside the function, not cat.

Comment: Maybe it's because you have two closing `});` lines.

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve your issues.

```
var cat = $('.option_category').each(function(){
    var cat_id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(cat_id);
});
```

As an aside, the `id` attribute is for identification. I do not know your implementation, however, if you trying to pass data through the `id`, I would look into the `value` parameter of the `option` tag or `data` attributes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: Thanks. That did help a lot. I have other elements I need to preform some checkering on that also use the category id. So I first need to grab all the category ID's.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify parameters in the function inside .each();

I made a working example for you. Demo in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7yb0boL3/)

Example code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery(".option").each(function(index, element){
        alert(index);
        alert(jQuery(element).html());
        alert(jQuery(element).attr('id')); //for getting id
    });

});
```

Html:

```
<html>
       <head>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div class="option" id="first_option">First option</div>
          <div class="option" id="second_option">Second_option</div>
          <div class="option" id="third_option">Third option</div>
       </body>
 </html>
```